# different format of time - how to read it in? R, readr

Tags: r, parsing, readr

I've got a file which includes the column with the recorded time of the event. Sometimes the time is in a format mm:ss and sometimes it has additional zeros at the end - mm:ss:00. See example below:

```
id    time
1     20:50
2     76:58:00
3     56:13:00
4     03:44
```

When I am reading this data in using `read_csv` all the values in a shorter format (mm:ss) are marked as `NA`. When I set this values to be read in as strings using `read_csv('data.csv', col_types = cols(time = col_character()))` all the values are changed to shorter format (so I've got `76:58` in the second row). How can I parse this `time` column to have all the data in one format (no matter if shorter or longer one), but as `time` type of variable and without loosing the data for these inputs which are in shorter format?

Why exactly all 8-character values are replaced with 'NA' while parsing as time?

Comment: I do not have the `read_csv` issue using your example data. This suggests the issue lies with your file `data.csv`.

Answer (score 0):

What about the following?

```
as.ms <- function(x) {
    unlist(lapply(sapply(x, function(w)
        strsplit(as.character(w), ":")), function(w) {
            if (length(w) == 2) {
                w[2] <- sprintf("%s.00", w[2])
            } else {
                w[2] <- sprintf("%4.2f", as.numeric(w[2]) + as.numeric(w[3]) / 1000);
            }
            w <- paste0(w[1:2], collapse = ":");
        }
    ))
}


lubridate::ms(as.ms(df$time));
#[1] "20M 50S" "76M 58S" "56M 13S" "3M 44S"
```

Explanation: `as.ms` adds fractional seconds if necessary; then you can use `lubridate::hms` to parse times.

This method will also work if you have milliseconds. For example, consider

```
df2 <- read.table(text =
    "id    time
1     20:50
2     76:58:00
3     56:13:250
4     03:44", header = T);
```

then

```
lubridate::ms(as.ms(df2$time));
#[1] "20M 50S"    "76M 58S"    "56M 13.25S" "3M 44S"
```

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "id    time
1     20:50
2     76:58:00
3     56:13:00
4     03:44", header = T);
```

Comment: The values are MM::SS or MM::SS::00, not HH::MM::SS.

Comment: Damn it; didn't read carefully enough. Ok, thanks for pointing this out @neilfws. I'll remove this shortly.

Comment: Should be fixed now. I've made changes such that it can also deal with milliseconds, e.g. "time = 56:13:250".

Comment: @MauritsEvers Unfortunetely, using `ms` function is not an option in my case as I need to sort these values further and `arrange` seems to not work with duration object. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @jakes `arrange` should work just fine with time@dates. Not sure what you think the issue would be.

Comment: @MauritsEvers it sorts by seconds, and I would obviously like to sort by minutes first, then the seconds. Please take a look on following example `x <- tribble( ~id, ~time, 1, "20:50", 2, "76:58:00", 3, "56:13:00", 4, "03:44" ) x <- x %>% mutate(time = substr(time, 1, 5), time2 = ms(time)) x %>% arrange(time2)`

Comment: @jakes; ah yes you're right. `POSIXct` time&dates are fine with `arrange`; `POSIXlt` and `lubridate::interval` objects are not. Perhaps the easiest way would be to `strsplit` or `tidyr::separate` on `":"`, then store duration in mins and seconds in separate columns; you can then use `arrange` to sort rows based on values in these two columns.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the first issue (short/long format): assuming that all values for `time` are either 5 characters (MM:SS) or 8 characters (MM:SS:00), you can convert to a short format like this, assuming the data frame is named `df1`:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  mutate(time = substring(time, 1, 5)) 

  id   time
1  1  20:50
2  2  76:58
3  3  56:13
4  4  03:44
```

This format allows us to use the `ms` function from the `lubridate` package. Note that your values are **not times** (as in times on a clock) - they are durations. So you can convert to a Period object like this:

```
library(lubridate)
df1 %>% 
  mutate(time = substring(time, 1, 5), 
         ts   = ms(time))

  id  time      ts
1  1 20:50 20M 50S
2  2 76:58 76M 58S
3  3 56:13 56M 13S
4  4 03:44  3M 44S
```

`lubridate` also has a `duration` function, which would require more formatting of the short format (the addition of "M" and "S").

Comment: The first part is not applicable in my case as I already have the shorter (5-characters) format when I'm parsing as character using `read_csv('data.csv', col_types = cols(time = col_character()))`. The second one helps to represent the values, but as I further need to sort them it's rather useless in my case (`arrange()` doesn't seem to work with values formatted by `ms()`.

So basically, I think that what I need to achieve is to keep these values as `time` without obtaining `NAs`. 

Actually, do you know why exactly parsing as `time` replaces 8-character values with `NA`?

Comment: I cannot reproduce either of your problems. Using your `read_csv` command I get both the 5 and 8 character format in the tibble. And I can arrange or sort Period objects. I think there must be some issue with your data which is not apparent in your example.

Comment: `x <- tribble( ~id, ~time, 1, "20:50", 2, "76:58:00", 3, "56:13:00", 4, "03:44" ) x <- x %>% mutate(time = substr(time, 1, 5), time2 = ms(time)) x %>% arrange(time2)` This seems to arrange the period values with respect to seconds. How to change this to sorting by minutes first, then seconds?

Comment: There do seem to be issues using tibbles or tribbles, as opposed to data frames (which I used initially). But it's the weekend, I'll look into it next week :)